# DBMS_CRYPTO.ENCRYPT returning random 16 bytes intermittently

Tags: database, oracle, plsql

I have used DBMS_CRYPTO.ENCRYPT to encrypt my JSON CLOB data and recently it has started behaving differently, generating random 16-byte data instead of the original value.

I get the JSON clob value perfect in every case when I added a few debug in the package but after DBMS_CRYPTO.ENCRYPT, sometimes it creates random data intermittently which causes issue.

When I run a sample code in APEX SQL commands and loop it to 500 times, then it works fine no issue in DBMS_CRYPTO.ENCRYPT but in package it is causing issue recently.

Here is sample code

```
declare
    V_ENC_BLOB BLOB;
    V_PR_K ITV_APP_PP.PR_K_SERVER%TYPE := 'A9BAB229027DF8C149332ADD5D61D827FC04BB53074AC96DFEE437EB46A64E60';
    V_PP_IV ITV_APP_PP.PP_IV_SERVER%TYPE := '3EF92D7687491A8E1A3102867B75531D';
    V_DATA_CLOB CLOB;
    V_ENC_BLOB_LEN PLS_INTEGER := 0;
    V_ENC_BLOB_LEN_STR VARCHAR2(1000);
    G_ENCRYPTION_TYPE PLS_INTEGER := DBMS_CRYPTO.ENCRYPT_AES256 + DBMS_CRYPTO.CHAIN_CBC + DBMS_CRYPTO.PAD_PKCS5;
begin
    for i in 1..100 loop
        DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY(V_DATA_CLOB, TRUE);
        DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY(V_ENC_BLOB, TRUE);
        select log_clob into V_DATA_CLOB from itv_dev_logs where log_id = 47128135;
        DBMS_CRYPTO.ENCRYPT(V_ENC_BLOB, V_DATA_CLOB, G_ENCRYPTION_TYPE, V_PR_K, V_PP_IV);
        V_ENC_BLOB_LEN := DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(V_ENC_BLOB);
        IF MOD(LENGTH(V_ENC_BLOB_LEN),2) != 0 THEN
            V_ENC_BLOB_LEN_STR := '0' || V_ENC_BLOB_LEN;
        ELSE
            V_ENC_BLOB_LEN_STR := V_ENC_BLOB_LEN;
        END IF;
        dbms_output.put_line(i || ' - '|| V_ENC_BLOB_LEN);
        dbms_output.put_line(i || ' - ' || V_ENC_BLOB_LEN_STR);
        DBMS_LOB.FREETEMPORARY(V_ENC_BLOB);
        -- IF V_DATA_CLOB IS NOT NULL THEN
        -- DBMS_LOB.FREETEMPORARY(V_DATA_CLOB);
        -- END IF;
        end loop;
end;
```

Could someone please suggest to me how can I debug further, and what things should I check?

Is there any patch that we may need to apply to DB?

I am using Oracle DB 18c. (Oracle Database 18c Enterprise Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production)

Thanks

I tried to debug with a copy package and we tried multiple web service calls but it happens randomly from package.

Comment: Just a suggestion that you may not want to publish what appears to be your *actual* encryption keys with your code to a public forum...

Comment: Thanks @pmdba. The keys added are dummy keys only.